# How to integrate easybib form Decorators in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, decorator, easyb

I am newbie to Zend framework. I want to learn **Decorators and Bootstrap**.

I have downloaded zip file from **https://github.com/easybib/EasyBib_Form_Decorator** link.
I want to integrate **easybib form decorators** in my **zend** project, but I dont know how to do exactly this?

Please tell me the steps to integrate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download it, extract the EasyBib Folder to \library\EasyBib in your project.
Now add it to your Autoloader in application.ini:

```
autoloadernamespaces.3 = "EasyBib_"
```

After this you can use it with Zend_Form like:

```
Class My_Form extends EasyBib_Form {}
```

See the Examples inside Download package!

Comment: Thanks ArneRie for your reply. I hav tried the above methods in my project. But didnt worked, can please guide me the steps?

Comment: No I m not gettng any error. Can u please provide me one example?

Comment: There are examples in the download (/examples)